# sql mybatis not saving list of objects

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I am trying to save list of objects using mybatis `SQL`. I have for each loop and merge and insert queries in `XML` file.

Problem I am facing is- only last object is running twice in loop, as I have 2 objects in list instead one by one.

Can someone please help on this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the following info to the question : 1) mapper statement that contains foreach 2) class definition of the parameter object 3) Java code that prepares the parameter objects 4) both expected and actual table data after the execution. Or, create a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) and share it on GitHub or somewhere.

Comment: Fixed now, thanks.